# When using an ndarray to represent a matrix, how to modify a column based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Numpy's documentation suggests to use numpy arrays to represent matrices, so I'm looking at something like

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

to represent

[image]

and I just can't figure out from the documentation how I would update a column based on the value of another column. Say, how would I do something like: If, in any row, the value in the second column is > 3, then add 10 to the third? Ie, in my example, I'd like to obtain:

[image]

Alternatively, kindly advise if there is some conceptional misunderstanding on my part about ndarrays. I'm really new to this...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'if the second column is > 3". How can a column of three numbers be greater than 3?

Comment: It might help to know that column j (for j = 0,1,2,3 in this case) is given by `arr[:,j]`.

Comment: there is no 10th col in your example...3rd coloumn >3? Like entire 3rd column or index?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, I hope my latest edit clarified what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific task you're interested can be done as follows

```
arr[arr[:,1]>3,2] += 10
```

Comment: This uses boolean indexing, see the [documentation here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).